# Options to a command specified in a file

Tags: shell, options

How can I have *some* of the options to a unix command come from a file? That is the file does *not* contain *all* the options -- other options are specified elsewhere.

For example I have the file`lsoptions.txt` with the following content:

```
-F -G
```

Now I would like to execute

```
ls -a <and all options specified in the file lsoptons.txt>
```

ie, I want to execute `ls -a -F -G`.

That is, specify some of the options, but other options are read from a file.

### Note:

- This is obviously a cooked up example. My real use case is that my shell script needs some parameters that were provided in a `TeX` file. So, instead of having the user duplicate the information in multiple places, I will have the `TeX` write the desired options into a file so that the shell script can also have access to them. One option would be to have the `TeX` generate the entire script, but would much easier if I could just read the options from a file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the trivial example listed above,

```
ls -a $(cat lsoptions.txt)
```

Comment: Am glad that that was easy. Will try that out.

Comment: With bash, you can use the builtin `$(< lsoptions.txt)`